# The monotonicity of the entropy operator

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

Define the entropy operator of a distribution as $\mathbb{H}(p) = -\int p \log p$, how does the entropy change for distributions that are proportional to the powers of $p$?

For example, define $\tilde{p} = \frac{\sqrt{p}}{\int \sqrt{p}}$, can we say anything about the relation between $\mathbb{H}(p)$ and $\mathbb{H}(\tilde{p})$? If such a general rule is impossible, what if we restrict $p$ to be in certain families of distributions (e.g. exponential family)?

Answer (score 0):

The paper

"Capacity bounds via duality with applications to multiple-antenna systems on flat-fading channels (Lapidoth-Moser-2003)"

has some nice results. For example:

$$h(log(X))=h(X)-\mathbb{E}[log(X)],$$
$$h(X^2)=h(X)+\mathbb{E}[log(X)]+log(2),$$

which are basically derived by change of random variable and considering the Jacobian of the transformation. For powers of $X$ also, you can consider change of random variable and the corresponding Jacobian of COV.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reference. Will give it a careful read!

Comment: However, I'm more interested in the setting where how H(Y) relate to H(X) if the density of Y is proportional to the square root of the density of X, i.e. X does not equal Y^2 in general

Comment: Well, you mean for example to consider $-\int \sqrt{f(x)} \log\left(\sqrt{f(x)} \right) \mathrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{f(x)} \log\left(f(x) \right) \mathrm{d}x$, and try to relate it to $-\int f(x) \log\left(f(x) \right) \mathrm{d}x$? I'm almost sure, there does not exist any general relation.